# How to Build Content Module

Tags: build, chromium

I have downloaded Chromium's source code and there is so called content module + content_shell (which is a basic browser built using content module). I want to build these two. I can't find any useful documentation on this. I see some gypi files but have no idea how to use them.

P.S. Is there any package where I can download Content API  + Content Shell only? So that they both would be absolutely separate from the rest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to follow one of the following build instructions: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows or 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/MacBuildInstructions or
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions. Once you know how to build on the appropriate platform, the target you want to build is "content_shell". For example, on Linux, to build content_shell in debug mode, you'd use ninja like so:

```
ninja -C out/Debug -j10 content_shell
```

Answer (score 0):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/testing/web_tests_in_content_shell.md

```
autoninja -C out/Default blink_tests
```